# the quality of having technical expertise is called?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

I have to write three qualities, which a successful person possesses. I thought of

1. creativity
2. resilience
3. knowledge - Here knowledge is not the quality of a successful person as per my teacher. But I want to convey that having technical expertise makes a person successful. I want to have the term for this third quality.

What is the quality of having technical expertise? I searched over the net and found that

> Technical skills, also known as hard skills, are qualities acquired by using and gaining expertise in performing physical or digital tasks.

and definition of hard skills as per investopedia is

> Hard skills are learned abilities acquired and enhanced through practice, repetition, and education. Hard skills are important because they increase employee productivity and efficiency and subsequently improve employee satisfaction.

Is it right to say the quality of having technical expertise is hard skills? or any better terminology?

The story for the 3. Knowledge is: I was referring to a story of an technical expert, where the complete shut down of a company (for example complete Electricity or machinery shut down)happened and nobody can fix and they asked for external help. the expert fixed the issue by doing a simple task ( say changing just fuse) and charged heavily and when asked why he charged he mentioned to fix it $1  and to know what to fix it $99. ( Here the technical expertise to know what to change is 99 times more worth than just doing the work. that ‘s what I wanted to explain)

Comment: Are we talking any particular skills? Crafts, IT, sports, outdoorsmanship, different technical occupations have different terminology. "Technical expertise" is a reasonably clear, neutral, general expression.

Comment: Your question is confusing since "the quality of having..." denotes an adjective, but in the rest of your context, you seem to be looking for a noun for such a person, not an adjective to describe such a person, so with that in mind, a couple of nouns for that are "techie" and "tech whizz." Another thing that's unclear is if you mean technical expertise in general or specifically technical expertise in computers, or are you using computers solely as an example? Some terms for someone with technical expertise specifically in computers are "computer nerd," "computer wonk," and "computer whizz."

Comment: Here is some information Cascabel, Benjamin Harman.  “Think of a quality which a successful person possesses.

1. creativity
2. resilience 
3. knowledge  - Knowledge is not a quality of a successful person as per my teacher. But having technical expertise makes a person successful. I want to have the term for this third quality.”

Comment: You are looking for *competence*. Also, success is orthogonal to all of these. A successful person does not have to possess any or all of them.

Comment: Could you update your question with an example sentence showing how you’d like to use this word?

Comment: I would say hard skills, knowledge and experience are what make up technical expertise. Don’t know if I’d necessarily include creativity, though. As for the whole “successful” person thing, I assume you are defining successful as “someone who makes a lot of money”. Your teacher has knowledge, but doesn’t make much money. Therefore, they are not successful. In this view, a person with technical expertise has knowledge, skills and experience others do not. Whether they are successful depends on if there is high demand for what they do. Tech experience alone does not equate success.

Comment: RegDwight, thanks the Competence looks as the quality of having knowledge/technical expertise. you mentioned that all three of them are orthogonal. I might agree to some extent. In your own terms what are the major 3 qualities of a successful person?

Comment: Performative expertise is called [chops](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chops). It's common to use the suffix -fu in a similar way, as in Google-fu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through and reviewing the comments, I will go with “Competence” as the quality of having technical Expertise.

As per the further search and study, I can think of the following are the 5 qualities to become a successful, I believe now.

1. Aspiration
2. Drive
3. Willingness to learn
4. Patience
5. Discipline

https://www.google.com.sg/amp/s/www.entrepreneur.com/amphtml/315161